# Is it possible to add ctm material plugin to blender?

Tags: blender

I would like to add a plugin to import and export .ctm files to blender (version 2.78). Is it possible? If yes, then how can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Blender provides a [python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current) to access it's data, which is used to create [addons](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/addons.html). Most of the included import/export functionality in blender is provided by addons written in python.

If you can read a .ctm file using python, then you should be able to re-create it in blender.

To get started, there is an addon tutorial [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html), you can also look through the existing import/export [Addons](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/) included with blender and you can find some more in the [Addons Contrib](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/) repo, the import/export addons have names starting with `io_`.

You can get blender specific help with python coding at [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com)